# How do I upload a file in Mercurial from my local repository?

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial newbie here, I have a simple question.

I deleted one of my files from Mercurial and I want to get it back. I used to do `svn up` in Subversion, but in Mercurial it doesn't work, I tried `hg up`, and it does nothing.
I tried `hg up` to a specific file, and surprisingly (to me..) it told me:

```
abort: unknown revision '74656d706c617465732f6c6f67696e2e68746d6c'!
```

I tried to specify a revision and it told me:

```
abort: please specify just one revision
```

Isn't there a simple way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hg revert`.

```
hg revert -r REV path/to/file
```

where `REV` is the revision of the repository that contains the file you want to recover.  See `hg help revert` for details.

Comment: and `hg status` to find out what the status is, it probably shows up as missing (`!`).